# Fetching next row based on data of current row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one sql table something like this

```
fist_name|last_name
asd      | fgh
qwer     | ijkl
yuio     | zsef
...      |  ....
```

The data is arranged sequentially like the above,

I am assigning the retrieved value to some string (let Str) for each row.

I want to create a function with parameters `(String str, mode)`
such that ,

```
if mode = 'GET', It will assign the first row to the string,
```

and

```
if mode = 'NEXT', It will read the string then assign the next row to the string
```

and return the string. I have DB on oracle.
Also I can't modify the DB (else I would have add some ID related to each entry)

It could be done using if-else for small table, but for large table it's not feasible.
Is there some way by which I could get the exact row_number assigned to each rows.

```
eg:
f1("qwerijkl","NEXT) => "yuiozssef";
f1("",'GET') -> "asdfgh";
```

Comment: Where do you want to call this function: SQL, PL/SQL, external programming language?

Comment: Is it necessary to use a custom function? This can be achieved in a simpler way. Or what other needs do you have?

Comment: In programming language. C program

Comment: Yeah I need a custom function, If there is other other simpler way , I will try to replicate the same in the function. 
@nayi224, If you know any way, can you please share some references.

Comment: `get` should return the row with the passed value or should always return the first (ordered by some criteria)?

Comment: Currently there is no ordering scheme for the DB. So `GET` should return first row on the table, (I think using `rownum=1`, will do that)

Comment: Be careful. Without an `order by` clause, there is no such thing as the *first* row in a table. There is no guarantee that a subsequent select on the same table will return the same row as the first row, even when that row has been neither deleted nor updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting using rowid is not good, you'd better set another sort column

```sql
select aa into res from (
    select t1.first_name || t1.last_name aa
      from 
    (
    select * 
      from tab t1 
     where 'GET' = P_MODE
     order by t1.rowid
    ) t1
     where rownum = 1
     
    union all

select t1.res
  from (
    select lead(t1.first_name || t1.last_name) over(order by t1.rowid) res,
         t1.*
      from tab1 t1
     where 'NEXT' = P_MODE
) t1
 where t1.first_name || t1.last_name = P_STR
) t1
```

If you use a function, you can put this SQL into the function, or you can query it directly.

Comment: I tried this oracle sql developer, the select lead () statement is returning null. 





`select lead(t1.last_name) over(order by t1.rowid) from t1 where last_name='ijkl';`

Comment: There is indeed an error, it has been corrected

Comment: Its working. Thanks for the reply @nayi224.

Comment: what if 1 or 2 column is blob. And I want `select blob1,blob2, string` as output.

Comment: Also what happen if we get duplicate data.  Is there a way where in `where` clause I can use current rowid ?

Comment: Blob can be converted to varchar.

Comment: It depends on what kind of duplicate data is and what rules you want to use to remove duplicate data.But how to remove duplicate data is a hot question, you should be able to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need an order. `first_name, last_name` or `last_name, first_name` would be appropriate choices here.

A function could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_name
(
  p_mode       in      varchar2,
  p_firstname  in out  varchar2,
  p_lastname   in out  varchar2
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
BEGIN
  SELECT p_firstname, p_lastname
  INTO p_firstname, p_lastname
  from names
  WHERE p_mode = 'GET'
     OR firstname > p_firstname
     OR (firstname = p_firstname and lastname > p_lastname)
  ORDER BY firstname, lastname
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;

  RETURN 'okay';
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  RETURN 'no more rows';
END get_name;
```

(It may be faster, though, to create a materialized view instead with `ROW_NUMBER` where `GET` would simply get the row #1, while `NEXT` would retrieve the row number for the name given and select the name for the following number.)

Here is a script to test above function:

```
DECLARE
  v_firstname varchar2(100);
  v_lastname varchar2(100);
  v_result varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  v_result := get_name('GET', v_firstname, v_lastname);
  IF v_result = 'okay' then
    dbms_output.put_line(v_firstname || ' ' || v_lastname);
  END IF;

  WHILE v_result = 'okay' LOOP
    v_result := get_name('NEXT', v_firstname, v_lastname);
    IF v_result = 'okay' then
      dbms_output.put_line(v_firstname || ' ' || v_lastname);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;  
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Thorsten, I am ordering it with rowid for now.

Answer (score 1):

You may use subquery with `offset ... fetch first ...` with additional check of previous value. But if you need to process all the values, then it would be better to open a cursor with `order by`, then fetch row by row and process the result.

Below is the code. You may use the query from function definition and replace parameters with bind variables.

> ```
> select *
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
> FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME
> :--------- | :--------
> 0001       | 1        
> 0002       | 22       
> 0003       | 333      
> 0004       | 4444     
> 0005       | 55555    
> 0006       | 666666   
> 0007       | 7777777  
> 0008       | 88888888 
> 0009       | 999999999
> ```

> ```
> with function f(
>   p_name varchar2
>   , p_method varchar2
> ) return varchar2
> as
>   l_res varchar2(1000);
> begin
>
>   with a as (
>     select
>       first_name || last_name as res
>       , lag(first_name || last_name)
>         over(order by first_name || last_name)
>         as prev_
>     from t
>     where first_name || last_name >= p_name
>       or p_method = 'GET'
>     order by 1
>     offset decode(p_method, 'GET', 0, 'NEXT', 1) rows
>     fetch next 1 rows only
>   )
>   select max(res)
>     into l_res
>   from a
> ```
>
> .      /*Additional check of previous value*/
> where prev_ = p_name
> or p_method = 'GET'
> ;
>
> ```
>   return l_res;
>   
> end;
>
> select
>   f('', 'GET') as get1,
>   f('qwe', 'GET') as get2,
>   f('000222', 'NEXT') as next1,
>   f('12', 'NEXT') as next2
> from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> GET1  | GET2  | NEXT1   | NEXT2
> :---- | :---- | :------ | :----
> 00011 | 00011 | 0003333 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8fdf523975b6b09974f2c94f602fc5ac)*

Comment: It seems you have taken order by first name ,last name.
The problem here is my actual table has lots of columns, and some columns are of blob type. Thus I too am not sure on which order to consider. As of now ordering by rowid seems feasible.

Comment: Obviously yes, because it is explicitly stated. And you didn't provide any ordering